# ASP.NET MVC:running under two different identities

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, impersonation

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET, hosting a simple MVC application on IIS.
In this project I need to integrate with two diferente sources:

1. A simple SQL database;
2. An already existing WCF Webservice over HTTP;

Users are able to authenticate in the website using Windows Authentication Credentials. This works as intended.

To query the database I use network user credentials, defined in the application pool. This also works just fine.

Now, my goal is to consume the web service while impersonating the logged in user. However, when I activate the ASP.NET Impersonate authentication method in IIS, the database connection is lost, as the logged in user identity is used, instead of the application pool's. On the other hand, deactivating ASP.NET Impersonation, I'm unable to authenticate against the web server because the application pool's identity is used.

I did try to deactivate ASP.NET impersonation in IIS, and use the `HTTPContext` user ID to impersonate the web service request in code. This leads to an error, stating that client header uses Negotiate while server uses Negotiate and NTLM.

Changing the service client bindings to use NTLM doesn't work.

Is there a way to authenticate in both services, one with the application pool's identity and the other with user log in (`HTTPContext`) Identity?

Comment: Is it an option to use a SQL Server user (username and password combination) in the connectionstring to the database? Doing so, you can activate impersonation for the webpages and services, and all database access goes via a wellknown account.

Comment: Yes, that would be my next plant. However, I really hate the idea of storing credentials in clear text on the configuration files. So, while searching for another solution I stumble across the option of ciphering these files. I'm still studying this method, but seems to be a viable idea.

Comment: Even removing the database from the equation, as soon as I activate ASP.NET Impersonation Authtentication, the connection with the webservice failed with error "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM, Negotitate'". I also checked the server and saw that no credentials were transmitted. After this I gave up on the webserver and used the provided Client dll. Everything works as expected now.